# owl-carousel Unable to preventDefault

Tags: google-chrome, owl-carousel

i searched for solution but couldn't find.

owl-carousel keep logs

> unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080

i'm using owl-carousel 2.2.0 which is https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2

Answer (score 10):

Solution - In owl.carousel.css add:

```
.owl-carousel 
{
    touch-action: manipulation; 
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I am using jQuery OwlCarousel v1.31

Answer (score 1):

You can use this css to fixed your bug

```
.owl-carousel {
  touch-action: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`touch-action: manipulation;`

This line saved me.

Answer (score 0):

For people here in the future if you still want to use (jquery based library) and the css solution above didn't work for you like me.
here's how I fixed it:

1. Download owl.carousel from their website to get the latest version
2. Replace owl.carousel.min.js with owl.carousel.js in your code to make the fix easier for your self.
3. Search and delete `Event.preventDefault()` from the file owl.carousel.js I found 2 of them in the code version (Owl Carousel v2.3.4).
4. Keep the following code in your css
    `.owl-carousel { touch-action: none; }` ***important*** or the screen will shake when users switch slides on mobile
5. Test that your slider are still working on touch screen and mouse

Answer (score 0):

.owl-carousel{touch-action: manipulation;}

Also this works for me.